# Best practice to follow in model in angular2(typescript)

Tags: class, angular, model-view-controller, model

I am working angualar2 application. In my app I am started creating class  for the model instead of interface which has the properties and function which I need on component here is my sample class for user

```
class User {
    private name: string;
    private lastName: string;
    constructor(name?: string, lastName?: string) {
        this.name = name || '';
        this.lastName = lastName || '';
    }
    validate() {
        if (!this.name.length) {
            throw 'Please enter name';
        }
        if (!this.lastName.length) {
            throw 'Please enter last name';
        }
    }
};
```

In given sample class has two property and on the function **(it may contains other function like addTiming, calSalary and many other that we need on user)** to validate user itself in a model the component I don't need to write code to validate user field and I can use that call everywhere in my app.

But I am not sure is that good practice to have the model like this.

Answer (score 0):

If form validation is not what you are looking for then try TypeScript decorators - you can make generic validators to use everywhere across your application, supporting DRY this way.
Here is some nice examples: https://github.com/pleerock/class-validator

Comment: Its not just validate function I will and many other functions which I need on user